# Get username of login

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Is it possible to get the username of someone who has succesfully authenticated through the htpasswd process and put that in a session variable?

`User: mave`
`Pass: mave123`

Successful login: write 'mave' to session?

Comment: Why didn't you check the documentation for HTTP Auth? http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: I didn't even know where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess cannot create or populate PHP session but you can get:

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']
```

value in your PHP code and store in session.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`, but I do not know if this works with htaccess, since it's not triggered by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As other users already answered, you can use the `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` to reference the user. But, it might fail if PHP is running in CGI mode. To set teh User/Pass server variables in CGI mode; add the following in you authorization directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, from PHP, you can use:

```
if( preg_match('/Basics+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'], $matches) ) {
    list($name, $password) = explode(':', base64_decode($matches[1]));
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = strip_tags($name);
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = strip_tags($password);
}
```